# Summing function in SQL adding zeros and NULLS how to avoid

Tags: sql, oracle, sum

I am trying to get only three columns back in my end result which would look like  outcome A below, but I am getting outcome B instead. I know it has to do with my NULLS and 0 but not sure how to exclude them? If I use a where clause I would need to have a WHERE clause in all three of my flags which not sure how to go about that

Outcome  A

```
R   DIA             SUD_FLAG_PER    ED_3_FLAG_PER
1   11.11111111     5.555555556      2.777777778
```

OUTCOME B - THIS IS WHAT I AM CURRENTLY GETTING

```
R   DIA             SUD_FLAG_PER    ED_3_FLAG_PER
1   11.11111111         0   
2   0               5.555555556 
3   0                    0  
4   0                    0          2.777777778
```

CODE

```
select


SUM(Diabetes_FLAG)*100/( SELECT percentt
                               from members) as DIA

,SUM(SUD_FLAG)*100/( SELECT percentt
                               from members) as SUD_FLAG_per 

,SUM(ED_3_FLAG)*100/(SELECT percentt
                               from members) as ED_3_FLAG_per                             


From prefinal

Group By Diabetes_FLAG ,SUD_FLAG ,ED_3_FLAG
```

here is the result from Prefinal Table..SORRY ABOUT THE FORMAT

```
MED_ID  ED_3_FLAG   SUD_FLAG    DIABETES_FLAG
99017471E       1    0              0
97483445D       0   0
93816600D   1   0   0
97696242G       0   0
95277731G       0   0
95235519A       0   0
90977691G       0   1
93793821A       0   0
96133532A       0   0
94378176C       0   0
94180014F       0   0
93391445F       0   0
98706680C       0   0
96478120E       0   0
92247933C       0   0
98591445F       0   0
98583717D       0   0
97258639C       0   0
90870338A       0   0
93695941A       0   0
91464685C       1   0
95994257F       0   0
94373524E       0   0
91373284C       0   0
97499504C       0   0
91677431D       0   0
99886113D       0   1
92964373F       0   0
90206268E       0   0
93208186A       0   0
92374509A       0   1
95879269E       0   0
92866204A       0   1
93741183C       0   0
90507292A       0   0
92867013C       0   0

members table results 

    PERCENTT
1   36
```

Comment: can you add current table result of table 'prefinal' and 'here'

Comment: Did you try without the `group by` clause?

Comment: I did remove the Group clause and I get an error " Not a single group-group function"

Comment: I did add the results from the two tables its pulling from as well

Comment: Which [DBMS product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Answer (score 3):

Try to JOIN the tables :

```
SELECT SUM(Diabetes_FLAG * 100/percentt) as DIA,
       SUM(SUD_FLAG * 100 / percentt) as SUD_FLAG_per,
       SUM(ED_3_FLAG * 100 / percentt) as ED_3_FLAG_per
  FROM prefinal CROSS JOIN members;
```

[***SQL Fiddle Demo***](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1e2c3/3)

Comment: Thank you so much!!! It worked perfectly ! I am going to have to read up on cross joins to see the logic behind it .. THANK YOU AGAIN !!